# Launching a flask app/website so other networks can connect

Tags: python, flask

So I've currently got a flask app that I'm using to run a testing app, (this works on local host) but I cant work out how to launch it so I can test the connectivity from other devices (public).

can someone explain how I can go about launching it, or at least point me in the right direction to some documentation about how to make it public. I don't think I'm either port forwarding it correctly or i need a web server like xampp to run it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

to make an application works with public host you have to make sure enabling port forwarding in your modem device, you can etablish a cnx with the nginx server

Comment: is that nginx server ran from my local device, so like xampp?

Comment: yes you can use like xampp

Comment: but you need some configuration with flask

Comment: do you know of any tutorials that cover the use of this?

Comment: look the  link cited above

Comment: sorry hadnt refreshed page, that link is coming up as a 404 error

Comment: http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/how-to-configure-nginx-for-a-flask-web-application/

Comment: try wth this new

Comment: sweet thanks ill take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

> It connects to the ngrok cloud service which accepts traffic on a
>   public address and relays that traffic through to the ngrok process
>   running on your machine and then on to the local address you
>   specified.

Basically you can access your local server from outside your network without port forward your router, it's good for testing and monitoring your apps.

Comment: I'm making a website so I want people to be able to connect and use the website so I'm not sure not port forwarding is a good solution

Answer (score 0):

If you change the ip address of the flask server from the default `0.0.0.0` to your the ip address of your computer (eg `192.168.1.2`) the other clients on your local network can connect.

If you want to expose your app the whole of the internet you should get a host that (eg try heroku.com) that has a fixed ip assigned and is reachable from the internet.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to host my own servers, so that's why i don't want to use a external host

Comment: that depens where the other devices are located. are the in the same netwokr or on the internet? If they are on the same network you can just do the change i describe otherwise it becomes more difficult.

Comment: i have a server computer on my desk that i run testing applications from